# Bounced Email / Invalid MIME Content

Tags: email, microsoft-office-365, email-bounces

Has anyone seen a bounced email because of the header size?

My Cisco Ironport appliance receives the following NDR when sending emails to Office365.

> bounced by destination server. Reason: 5.3.0 - Other mail system
> problem ('554', ["5.6.211 Invalid MIME Content: Single text value
> size (32837) exceeded allowed maximum (32768)

Comment: What did you do to verify your headers are properly folded?

Comment: I found out after I posted this that Ironport has bug and does not fold the header correctly. I'm going to have to create a policy to strip it out.